# Angular 5 Material Table ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material2

In my search component I have a table component with a property binding

`<app-attributes-table [data]="data"></app-attributes-table>`

My search service returns an observable of a custom type and the search component subscribes and sets `this.data` in the change handler. This updates the data variable in the table component which gets displayed as the search results.

```
this.searchService.getParts(this.search).subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data; 
}
```

When it is done the table component throws the following error:

> Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'error:
>   undefined'. Current value: 'error: undefined'. It seems like the view
>   has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty
>   checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?

Why does it think the expression changed after it was checked since the previous value and the current value are the same?  Perhaps this is a bug.

Comment: see this https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not thrown if change detection is run again in the child component after the view is initialized. I'm not sure I properly understand the mechanism properly and this might be completely circumventing it.

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```